# Openlayers 3 Is it possible to get features from an ol.source.VectorTile source?

Tags: javascript, maps, openlayers-3

I've got an ol.layer.VectorTile layer with an ol.source.VectorTile source that I'd like to get the closest individual feature to the mouse with, similar to ol.source.Vector's getClosestFeatureToCoordinate.

I found the features in the ol.source.VectorTile's tile cache, but haven't found the right API.. is there one?

Comment: Even a way to keep the features in sync with a separate ol.Collection would work